# parent class's constructer in a child class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, parent

I have one parent class and one child class.
The parent has a constructor that initializes its parameters.

My question is: How does the child look to the parent's constructor? Can I define a constructor for the children?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `base(...)` in ctor of your *child* class.

foreacmple:

```
public class Child : BaseClass 
{
    public Child() : base(/*some parameters*/) //CALLING BaseClass parametrized ctor
    {  
    }
}
```

Just note, if you don't need some specific parameters, just do not do *anything*, cause `BaseClass` default `ctor` will be called *by the way* when you call `ctor` of a `Child` class.

Comment: what if I create new constructor in the child class. The parameters will be initilized depending on the child's or parent's constructor?

Comment: if you use parametrized costructors, the only ctor of the base class that **can** be called **automatically** is *default* constructor. So in case of parametrized choose appropriate one from the abse ctors.

Answer (score 1):

This inheritance sample shows:

- how to call the parent constructor from a new constructor on the child
- how to pass parameters required by the parent constructor

Code sample:

```
public class Parent
{
    private object _member;

    public Parent(object member)
    {
        this._member = member;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(object member)
        : base(member)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Its really a helpful answer.

Comment: @AliEssa No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. When you find an answer to be helpful, you can vote it up. In case it is your own question you can mark an answer as the best by 'accepting' the answer.

Comment: I found that when I create one more constructor in the parent, I should create also a child constructor with the same parameters.

Comment: @Ali Essa. Correct. Parameters in constructors should be mapped. However, you can provide default values in the child: `public Child() : base(null)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define constructors for the children. You can call the base class' constructor using `: base()` between the constructor prototype and its implementation:

```
public class Parent {
  public Parent() {
    ...
  }
}

public class Child : Parent {
  public Child() : base() { // calls Parent.ctor
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

You are after the "base" keyword.

```
public class Fruit
{
    string TypeOfFruit { get; set; }

    public Fruit (string typeOfFruit)
    {
        TypeOfFruit = typeOfFruit;
    }

}

public class Apple : Fruit
{
    string AppleType { get; set; }

    public Apple(string appleType) : base("Apple")
    {
        AppleType = appleType;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well define a constructor for the child class the default one is provided only in case when you do not define a constructor for a class

Meanwhile for how to look up for the constructor of parent

It would check for a parameterless constructor to be present in the parent class and in case you do not have one ( well the compiler lets you know the same) or else you will have to call the parent constructor with the parameters like `base("This is the string parameter")`

If you meant something else please update the question.